# Dynamic SQL MERGE: Not a valid identifier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have written a stored procedure that we will use to dynamically generate merge code and synchronise datasets.

The merge code generates reliably but fails to execute with a

> 'NOT VALID IDENTIFIER'

error. I think it has something to do with how I am escaping varchar values but I can't seem to resolve it

I would appreciate any insight into where I am tripping up.

```
--CREATE TABLE dbo.temp_share_test
--(grp_id int not null,
--co_code varchar(10) not null,
--sp_no INT not null,
--sp_code varchar(10) not null,
--sp_type varchar(10),
--sp_colour varchar(10));

--alter table  dbo.temp_share_test add constraint pk_temp_share_test
--primary key (grp_id, co_code, sp_no, sp_code);

--insert into  dbo.temp_share_test (grp_id, co_code, sp_no, sp_code, sp_type, sp_colour)
--values 
--(2,'A',1,'X',1,'GREEN'),
--(2,'A',2,'Y',2,'BLUE'),
--(2,'A',3,'X',3,'YELLOW');

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql =   
'MERGE dbo.temp_share_test AS t 
USING (SELECT * FROM dbo.temp_share_test WHERE grp_id = 2 AND co_code = ''A'') AS s  
ON (t.grp_id = 2 AND t.co_code = ''H'' AND t.sp_no = s.sp_no AND t.sp_code = s.sp_code) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (grp_id, co_code,sp_code,sp_no,sp_type,sp_colour) 
VALUES (2, ''H'',s.sp_code,s.sp_no,s.sp_type,s.sp_colour);'
exec @sql;
```

Comment: You cant add same primary key,insert values must be 1,2,3,4 of grp_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) over`EXEC`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =   
'MERGE dbo.temp_share_test AS t 
USING (SELECT * FROM dbo.temp_share_test WHERE grp_id = 2 AND co_code = ''A'') 
       AS s  
ON (t.grp_id = 2 AND t.co_code = ''H'' AND t.sp_no = s.sp_no 
    AND t.sp_code = s.sp_code) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (grp_id, co_code,sp_code,sp_no,sp_type,sp_colour) 
VALUES (2, ''H'',s.sp_code,s.sp_no,s.sp_type,s.sp_colour);'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=17c91867d99a35c531c693ea7e31e390)**

When dealing with dynamic SQL I highly recommend to read: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Introducing)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the responses.

Simply adding brackets to the EXEC statement ('EXEC (@sql)') did allow command line execution but I was still not able to run from within the stored procedure. But all good now.

lad2025's link was a brilliant reference for both method and best practice.  Thank you.

SUM: key to executing a dynamic sql merge statement from within a stored procedure 
- use 'EXEC sp_executesql' with parameters. Far safer and avoids quote issues
- use nvarchars

Comment: It is exactly this. Take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql), you'll see that to "Execute a stored procedure or function" you don't need the brackets. However, to "Execute a character string" you MUST include the brackets.